# Why 'if' before preventDefault and stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

It's probably a rookie question but I can't either Google it or guess why it is this way.

```
el.addEventListener(
    'drop',
    function(e) {
        if(e.preventDefault) { e.preventDefault(); }
        if(e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
        //... some other code
```

now... I used to just implement:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

without any 'if's, can someone give me a hint why I should place ifs before?

Comment: To avoid problems if `preventDefault` is not present on the event object, which might be the case in certain older browsers.

Comment: It is used to ensure that ``e.preventDefault`` and ``e.stopPropagation`` are defined before calling them. Otherwise it may crash and the code after it will not be run (if either of them are not defined).

Comment: @Winestone - It won't make the page "crash".

Comment: Note that the if statements are _pointless_ in this case, as every browser that supports `addEventListener` also supports `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`.  If the events were being attached in a cross-browser manner, it would make sense.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah, I think "stop executing" might be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sure `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` indeed exist before executing them. Other ways of doing the same thing include:

```
var empty = function(){};
(e.preventDefault || empty)()
```

```
if(typeof e.preventDefault !== "undefined") e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: In the case of `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, it's IE 8 and below that don't have it defined. But IE 8 and below also don't have `addEventListener` defined so it's a little superfluous in OP's question.

Comment: @stevuu - Maybe `addEventListener` is modified by a library and `preventDefault` may not always exist? This might be one reason why this is used.

Comment: yes so the main purpose would be backward compatibillity - thank you.

Comment: Since the Event object is a host object, and *preventDefault* is a host method, `typeof e.preventDefault` may not return *function*. Also, it may exist but not be callable (stranger things have happened in browser–land), so `if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault()` is probably sufficient, or maybe even `e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah I was adding information, not refuting yours!